# New Window is not recognizing by watir-webdriver on IE11 for our site

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, cucumber, watir-webdriver

Watir-webdriver is not able recogzine the new window for our site. I tried with ohter site, it is working fine , but comming to our site its not happening

scenario : 
1. Log into to the site
2. Click on a button 
3. It will display new window with some data to modify

Is there any thing to check in depth for this windows identifying.
I tried with - index, name also, still no use.

Please help me if you have any suggestion.

Comment: Is it an actual browser window - ie if you output `browser.windows.count` has the count actually increased? Dialogs (eg `div` tags styled to look like a window) would be elements in the page rather than a window.

Comment: Its window only, they are opening new window using "window.open(url)" in java script windows count is not getting increased and showing it as 1 even it has two windows in UI

Comment: <TABLE width="50%" border=0 name="tblButtons"><TBODY>
<TR>
<TD width="50%" align=center><INPUT onclick=Details() class=Button style="WIDTH: 150px" type=button value="Details" name=Details>
</TD></TR>  -- This is the button which is showing up window after clicking on it

Comment: That's interesting. Are you able to try using Chrome and Firefox? It might help to determine if it's a Watir problem vs a driver problem.

Comment: That website will work only in IE only. So I could not verify it. What else can I check to determine it..

Comment: Will it be related to any security tab settings in IE

Comment: Is the popup opened in the same zone as the main page? I remember reading about issues during that scenario. You might need to set the [ignoreProtectedModeSettings setting](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities).

Comment: Yeah, But protectedmode settings are disabled due to security reasons , so I started with Watir-Classic which will directly invoke native IE browser.

Comment: You'll want to be careful about using Watir-Classic. It won't work once IE11 is no longer supported by Microsoft.